# Exchange 2019, modify AddressList

Tags: exchange

Information stored in AD, for example IP Phone, Mobile and so on do not displayed in users Outlook>Contacts. As I understand I must use:
Set-AddressList -Identity "All Users List" -IncludedRecipients AllRecipients -ConditionalCustomAttribute1 "ipPhone"

But I would like more clarity on whether I am doing everything right and how to add other parameters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contacts in Outlook are an Outlook feature which is not associated with Exchange, which means it does not directly get the information from AD like Exchange.

If you want to see the Exchange users' information, you should use address book instead.

(You can add the users to Outlook contacts from address book)

Example:
[image]

```
Set-AddressList -Identity "All Users List" -IncludedRecipients AllRecipients -ConditionalCustomAttribute1 "ipPhone"
```

This cmdlet creates an address list and adds users who has "ipPhone" value in their custom attribute1.

This has nothing to do with your requirement.